# How to create dynamic variables with incremented divs?

Tags: jquery

I have 2 div sets that are incremented, but now I need to pull information such as the title and link from one, and wrap it around the second. I started to set my vars like so:

```
  var title = $(".hs-rss-title span").html();
  var link = $('.hs-rss-title').attr('href').split('=');
```

But when I wrap this in via an each-loop, it only uses the first example of the given selector. How could I best do this so that it pulls each individual selector for each element with the incremented div?

I am trying to wrap each of my div `circle` + `k+1` divs with the `<a>`tag. Using this snippet below, I am receiving duplicated links.

```
$(".gs-rss-feed .hs-rss-item").each(function(i) {
    $(this).addClass("step" + (i + 1));
    $("#map .circle").eq(i).addClass("filled");
      var title = $(".hs-rss-title span").html();
      var link = $('.hs-rss-title').attr('href').split('=');
    $("#map .circle").eq(i).wrap("<a href="+link+"></a>");

  });
```

Any ideas on how to go about this?
[codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/Ogzzrx?editors=0010).